# Flutter Sending variable with api data to another class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have an app which gets data from the backend. I used a FutureBuilder and for the most classes when i try to pass the variable that im getting data, it's successfully being send to the other classes and i use the variable. But in another case i try to pass the variable to the other class and it's failing saying that null is being returned from the api.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder<Response>(
    future: futureDataForStatus,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        WorkingLocationStatus accountInfo = WorkingLocationStatus.fromJson(
          json.decode(snapshot.data!.body),
        );
 
        sendAccountInfo(){
         return IsUserWorking(accountStatus: accountInfo.status,);
        }
-------------
 
class IsUserWorking extends StatelessWidget {
  const IsUserWorking({
    Key? key,
    this.accountStatus,
  }) : super(key: key);
 
  final String? accountStatus; // according to debugger its returning null 
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (accountStatus == 'NOT_WORKING') {
      return const WorkingScreen();
    }
    return const StopWorkingScreen();
  }
}
 
------ 
 
// what the api returns 
 
when the user is not working api returns this
 
{"status":"NOT_WORKING"}
 
but if the user is working it returns this
 
{"status":"WORKING","name":{"locationName":"Gjakova e Re","location":"Rruga Besmir Haxhi Koci, nr 577","startTime":"2022-02-28T21:16:38.510879+01:00","endTime":null,"duration":"PT10.256862755S"}}
```

// same variable passing to other classes

```
return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder<Response>(
    future: futureDataForStatus,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        WorkingLocationStatus accountInfo = WorkingLocationStatus.fromJson(
          json.decode(snapshot.data!.body),
        );
 
LocationNameData(accountInfo: accountInfo), //works fine
LocationData(accountInfo: accountInfo), // works fine
WorkingStartTime(accountInfo: accountInfo), // works fine
 
class LocationNameData extends StatelessWidget {
  const LocationNameData({
    Key? key,
    required this.accountInfo,
  }) : super(key: key);
 
  final WorkingLocationStatus accountInfo;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                children: [
                  const TextSpan(
                    text: 'Status: ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Color(0xFF616161),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: accountInfo.status, // works just fine
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

// function to fetch the data

```
Future<Response> getLocationStatus(BuildContext context) async {
  final navigator = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? authorization = prefs.getString('authorization');
  var url = 'url';
  locationStatus = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'authorization': authorization ?? basicAuth.toString(),
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  );
  print('qqqqqqqqqqqq${locationStatus!.statusCode}');
  return locationStatus!;
}
```

Comment: The method is necessary just return IsUserWorking Widget and pass the data. It'll be good to see the complete future builder too.

Comment: that's what i done right

Comment: i passed the data on the IsUserWorking and i showed the FutureBuilder. If you could explain with code what you mean it would be great

Comment: sorry that was a typo, I meant unnecessary not the other way. The return keyword would handle showing the IsUserWorking widget and the data will be passed normally

Comment: So do i remove 'return' and would that make it any different because now it's failing, in the IsUserWorking is saying that accountStatus is null so im not getting any data from the api

Comment: Check the connectionstate of the future before you try to access the data. eg if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData). Also having only return IsUserWorking(accountStatus: accountInfo.status,); is not good, I think that might be the problem. Show a loading screen or a circular progress indicator as the final widget and then use the if condition above to return the widget you want once you know the data is available. Currently it is immediately shown before the future even completes. So even if you have the data it's too late.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ck7AbTrA

here is how i done it i have put the CircularProgressIndicator as the final widget but is still doesnt work, is there anything else missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242533/discussion-between-nana-kwame-and-learnflutter).